# Access to the template class constructor's parameter from the destructor, is it possible?

Tags: c++, oop, templates, constructor, destructor

I want to see how is possible to access the constructor's parameter from the destructor. In this example I want to modify the parameter from the constructor and  restore it in destructor.

```
template<typename T>
class sorted_array_view {
public:    
    sorted_array_view(T* givenArray,size_t size) {
         for( int idx = 0; idx < size; ++idx){
            data.push_back(givenArray[idx]);
            originaldata.push_back(givenArray[idx]);
         }
         std::sort(data.begin(), data.end());
         for(int idx =0; idx<size; ++idx){
            givenArray[idx] = data.at(idx);
         }
    }

    ~sorted_array_view(){
         for(int idx =0; idx<size; ++idx){
            givenArray[idx] = originaldata.at(idx);
         }
    }

private:
    std::vector<T> data;
    std::vector<T> originaldata;
};
```

But I got error `'givenArray' was not declared in this scope` at destructor. How can I access to the `givenArray`?

Comment: you can store the constructor's parameter in the class

Comment: @Tyker as a reference?

Comment: What is `givenArray` and why is it not a `std::vector`?

Comment: @KorteAlma - there's nothing stopping a reference being a member of a class, being initialised by the constructor, and accessed by the destructor.    It will be up to the user of the class to ensure the object being referred to still exists when the destructor uses it   (using a dangling reference  (aka a reference to an object that no longer exists gives undefined behaviour)).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Using more STL, your code can even become

```
#include <iostream>
#include <vector>
#include <algorithm>
template<typename T>
class sorted_array_view {
public:
    sorted_array_view(T* const givenArray, size_t size)
        : data(givenArray, givenArray + size)
        , originaldata(givenArray, givenArray + size)
        , givenArray(givenArray)
    {
        std::sort(data.begin(), data.end());
        std::copy(std::cbegin(data), std::cend(data), givenArray);
    }

    ~sorted_array_view() {
        std::copy(std::cbegin(originaldata), std::cend(originaldata), givenArray);
    }

private:
    std::vector<T> data;
    std::vector<T> const originaldata;
    T* const givenArray;
};

#include <array>
#include <iostream>
int main()
{
    std::array<int, 5> givenArray = { 4, 3, 5, 1, 2 };

    {
        sorted_array_view<int> sortTemp(&givenArray[0], givenArray.size());

        for (const auto& el : givenArray) std::cout << el << " "; std::cout << "\n";
    }
    for (const auto& el : givenArray) std::cout << el << " "; std::cout << "\n";
}
```

Output:

```
1 2 3 4 5 
4 3 5 1 2
```

[live example](http://rextester.com/GLWJM82372)

But it's dangerous to do too much in your constructor/destructor. <s>You cannot throw an exception from a destructor.</s> edit: see comment by Peter.

Comment: Exceptions can be thrown from destructors.   However, it is rarely a good idea in practice, since it severely limits utility of the object  e.g.  cannot be as easily stored/used in a standard container,  `std::terminate()` is called if the destructor is invoked during stack unwinding because another exception has been thrown, etc.

Answer (score 2):

Just make `givenArray` a data member of the class.

Then the destructor (and any other member function) will have access to it.

---

PS: Change the `size` in the destructor to `originaldata.size()`, if their value is going to be same (which seems to be case from your code). Otherwise, you will need `size` to become a data member too.

Comment: The originaldata vector already holds the size, just change `size` for `originaldata.size()`.

Comment: Thank you @MaLarsson, good observation, but only if `originaldata` won't change, I should mention that.

Answer (score 1):

In general, in a class, if you want to access an argument of a member function from another member function, you need to store that argument in the class.

Overall, simplifying your code, it gives:

```
template<typename T>
struct sorted_array_view
{    
    sorted_array_view(T* array, std::size_t size)
        : original_content{array, array+size}, original_container{array}
    {
        std::sort(array, array+size);
    }

    ~sorted_array_view()
    {
        std::copy(begin(original_content), end(original_content), original_container);
    }

private:
    std::vector<T> original_content;
    T*             original_container;
};
```

Full demo: http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/2958a997404bfaf9

Comment: Ah, you beat me too it, I was trying to be too complete ;)